# Menu bar fixed at top of the page when scrolling is causing content underneath to jump during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a submenu stay at the top of the page while scrolling once it reaches the top during scrolling. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {    
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 175) {
$('#location_menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top','0px').css('z-index','1000');
$('.first').css('padding-top','415');}
  else { 
$('#location_menu').css('position', 'relative').css('z-index','1');
 }});
```

The issue I'm having is that the scroll is not smooth and once the element changes from position:relative to position:fixed the content seems to jump/skip up about 415px which is the same height as the submenu.

Here is the css:

```
 <div id="location_menu" >submenu content
 </div>

 <div id="content" class="location_detail first">content beneath submenu
 </div>
```

I've added the line for `.first` to have a padding-top of 415px when the page is crolling and reaches within 175px of the top of the page `.css('padding-top','415')` this doesn't actually seem to be doing anything though. There is no change, so I assume I have executed it incorrectly.

Should I use a different scrolling function then I have listed above?

Here is what I ended up using to fix my problem, based off the code from @Danko :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var $conten = $('.first'),
      $menu = $('#location_menu')
      scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollpos >= 175) {
      $conten.css('padding-top','365px');
      $menu.css('position', 'fixed').css('top','0px').css('z-index','1000');
  } else {
      $conten.css('padding-top','0');
      $menu.css('position', 'fixed').css('position', 'relative').css('z-index','1');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Ok now that i understand the question, i did this demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdkLf.

The function in fact is this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var $menu = $('#location_menu'),
      $conten = $('#content'),
      scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollpos >= 175) {
      $menu.css( {
        "top" : "0",
        "position": "fixed",
      });
      $conten.css('top','375px' );
  } else {
      $menu.css( {
        "position": "relative",
        "top" : "175px",
      });
      $conten.css('top','175px');
  }
});
```

Here `175` is equals to the initial distance from the top and `375` is the addition between the distance and the `height` of your menu